# Can jooq be used to compare if two schemas are identical?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Can jooq be used to compare if two schemas are identical? Not the data but that the tables, constraints, permissions etc are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can compare all the things that are represented in the jOOQ API, including:

- Catalogs (SQL Server only)
- Schemas
- Tables
- Columns and their types
- User defined types
- Sequences
- Identities
- Constraints (including primary keys, unique keys, foreign keys, and check constraints)

What's not supported (yet, in jOOQ 3.9)

- Indexes (on the roadmap: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5638)
- Grants / permissions (not on the roadmap)
- Procedures (not comparable yet)

#### An example algorithm

... that compares two versions of the H2 `PUBLIC` schema:

```java
assertEquals(v1.Public.PUBLIC, v2.Public.PUBLIC);

List<Table<?>> tables1 = v1.Public.PUBLIC.getTables();
List<Table<?>> tables2 = v2.Public.PUBLIC.getTables();
assertEquals(tables1, tables2);

for (int i = 0; i < tables1.size(); i++) {
    Table<?> table1 = tables1.get(i);
    Table<?> table2 = tables2.get(i);

    assertArrayEquals(format("Fields differ for %s and %s", table1, table2),
        table1.fields(), table2.fields());
    assertEquals(format("Primary keys differ for %s and %s", table1, table2),
        table1.getPrimaryKey(), table2.getPrimaryKey());
    assertEquals(format("Schemas differ for %s and %s", table1, table2),
        table1.getSchema(), table2.getSchema());
    assertEquals(format("Identities differ for %s and %s", table1, table2),
        table1.getIdentity(), table2.getIdentity());
    assertEquals(format("Keys differ for %s and %s", table1, table2),
        table1.getKeys(), table2.getKeys());
    assertEquals(format("References differ for %s and %s", table1, table2),
        table1.getReferences(), table2.getReferences());
}
```

#### If you want to compare two different schemas for the same content

It'll get a bit more tricky because the jOOQ `QueryPart.equals()` implementations are usually based on either:

- `toString()` comparisons
- Qualified name comparisons

Since two different schemas will have different qualified names, you'll have to adapt the above algorithm and compare each object's `getName()` result, rather than the entire object.

#### Comparing XML content

Maybe that'll be easier for you... jOOQ 3.9 introduced the [`DSLContext.informationSchema()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#informationSchema-org.jooq.Schema-) methods with [#5460](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5460). These methods return JAXB-annotated classes, which can be marshalled to an XML string:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JAXB.marshal(ctx.informationSchema(mySchema), writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

And you could compare the two versions with any XML tool, e.g. with XSLT

#### If you just want to compare things manually

If you have two versions of the generated code, you could simply create a diff between the two directories or use your VCS to show you the diff ;-) Perhaps that's good enough.